# How to ease updating inferno with web performance test scripts

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, web-testing

Updating can performance test script e.g. with LoadRunner can take a lot of time and be quite frustrating. If there has been some updates with the applications, you usually have to run the script and then find out what has to be changed, update and run again and so on. Does anyone have some concrete best practices how to ease this updating inferno? One obvious thing is good communication with developers.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the kind of updates. If the update is dramatic, like adding new fields for user to fill in, then, someone has to manually touch up the test scripts.

If, however, the update is minor, for example, some changes to the hidden fields or changes to the internal names of user-facing fields,  then it's possible to write a script that checks the change and automatically updates the test script.

One of the performance test platforms, [NetGend](http://www.netgend.com), automatically takes care of the hidden fields and the internal names of user-facing fields so it's very easy to create a script to performance-test a HTML form. Tester only needs to fill in the values that he/she would have to enter using a browser, so no correlation is necessary there.   Please send me a message if you need to know more about it.

Comment: Script checking the changes sounds interesting. Any more information about that somewhere?

Comment: NetGend platform took care of it automatically, that's why I know it's possible. Don't know if there is an existing script to do it yet.  I have some rough idea on the implementation.  Have to try it out.   Can we take it offline? perftechy@gmail.com.  Thanks.

Comment: codingFun, your answer pattern shows a distburbing trend to recommend NetGend on just about every answer.  Please identify yourself if you are a vendor or a VAR for the solution.

Comment: James, sorry to see you used the word "disturbing",  you may want to read some of your own posts before you use it here :-)  Yes I work for netgend and I should have added a disclaimer. I was answering this question as an engineer trying to help my fellow engineers and pointed out that in theory this can be done when developers only tinkered with hidden fields etc (no change to what the form looks to a user). I know netgend tool well, hence I used it as an evidence.

Comment: For loadrunner, in pseudo-code,  I guess one can create an offline tool that can create the Loadrunner script (C code) automatically by doing the following steps:  do a HTTP transaction to get the HTML page and parse it, find the DOM element for the form and scan through the hidden fields, spit out the C code accordingly.  James, you are a guru in Loadrunner, maybe you can give JohnP a working example?

Answer (score 1):

There are many things you can do to insulate your scripts from build to build variability.   The higher up the OSI stack you go the lower the maintenance charge, but the higher the resource cost for the virtual user type.   Assuming changes are limited to page level resources and a few hidden fields here and there for web sites or applications, then you can record in HTML mode.   You blast the EXTRARES sections as the page parser in HTML mode will automatically parse the page and load the page resources even without an explicit reference - It can be a real pain to keep these sections in synch if you have developers who are experimenting quite a bit.

Next up, for forms which have a very high velocity in terms of change consider the use of a web_custom_request() for the one form.  You can use correlation statements to pick up all of the name|value pairs as needed and build the form submit dynamically.   There will be a little bit more up front work for this but you should have pay offs at around the fourth changed build where you would normally have been rebuilding some scripts.

Take a look at all of the hosts referenced in your code.   Parameterize all of these items.    I have a template that I use for web virtual users which pairs a default value and the ability to change any of the host names via the control panel extra attributes section.   Take a look at the example for lr_get_attrib_string() for how you might implement the pickup and pair that with a check for NULL and a population with a default value in your code

This is going to seem counter intuitive, but comment your script heavily for changes that are occurring often so you know where to take the extra labor change up front to handle a more dynamic data set.

Almost nothing you do with any tool can save you from struuctural changes in the design and flow of the app, such as the insertion of a new page in the workflow, but paying attention to the design on the high change pages, of which there are typically a small number, can result in a test code with a very long life.

Of course if your application is web services based then there is a natual long life to the use of exposed public services.   Code may change on the back end of the service, but typically the exposed public interface is very stable.

Comment: As an added item, many scripts fail from build to build due to changes in "the happy path," where code is not explicitly checking for expected results.   Take the time, check for the results, and then handle the unexpected result when it occurs or you will wind up with an HTTP 500 very rapidly.   This can be due to both application and data changes, so running a test which all of the sudden doesn't progress passed the third step will tell you volumes about the developer who suggested, "I didn't change anything..."